# Better keyboard on Nexus One?

Tags: nexus-one, keyboard

is there some easy way to get a better keyboard on the Nexus One? The default keyboard has way to small buttons and it's hard to use.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alternative keyboards](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/56/alternative-keyboards)

Comment: see also: phones with built-in QWERTY keyboards http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/187/what-are-some-good-android-phones-with-built-in-qwerty-keyboard

Answer (score 4):

There are a ton of keyboard apps out there -- check out the market for both free and paid.

I hate tapping and tapping, and there are at least two slide-the-finger virtual keyboards available:

Swype is my favorite -- but that's only been out in a limited beta for Android, so far. Maybe again....

ShapeWriter is a good substitute... but that's off the market due to a post-merger company re-org  (kids, THIS is why FLOS is a Good Idea). Hit up google, and you'll find a few people that have the .apk available, though. [Here's one](http://vivin.net/2010/06/22/download-shapewriter-apk/) (as of Sept 2, 2010).

[JetKeys](http://download.cnet.com/JetKeys/3000-2094_4-30838.html) is one of the weirdest that I've seen. Not a glider -- touch in the center of key, then slide in a direction to select alternate characters. Great idea, weird to use.

---

I have some more notes in a [blog post.](http://www.bestandroidresources.com/Blog/Data-Entry-for-the-touch-screen-challenged)

Comment: Can't really get Swype because of the beta. Would like to try shapewriter, but I really don't like downloading software that is not on the marketplace. So this question is still unsolved imho.

Comment: There is another slide-the-finger virtual keyboard called SlideIT.

Comment: Getting the Swype beta isn't difficult, but you do have to sign up. Then just download & install the Swipe Installer .apk and let it do its thing.

Answer (score 2):

The just-announced Android 2.3 has a much-improved keyboard. The Nexus One will almost certainly get Gingerbread, and sooner than most.

However, you can get the Gingerbread keyboard on your phone now. https://market.android.com/details?id=com.moo.android.inputmethod.latin.free

Comment: Video of the Gingerbread keyboard here, for those that like to see before they try: http://www.androidguys.com/2010/12/07/hands-gingerbread-keyboard/

Comment: it is now no longer necessary to be rooted to install Gingerbread keyboard on pre-Gingerbread phones: https://market.android.com/details?id=com.moo.android.inputmethod.latin.free

Comment: Cool. Thanks @Lie. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

There should be some stuff on XDA Developers (http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=560) just do some searching at that link. I've seen droid keyboards floating around and I bet someone has one ported for the Nexus.

I would also check out Swype (have to go to their website to get it http://www.swypeinc.com/) and Swiftkey Beta (can be downloaded from marketplace. Both of these are the best keyboards I have used because they both allow quick typing and aren't overly annoying with suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try SlideIt from the Android Market : - https://market.android.com/details?id=com.dasur.slideit.vt.lite&feature=search_result

Its much better than swype in my experience !

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [ThickButtons keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.thickbuttons) which I have been using for years. Free tool, and it uses predictive text algorithm to enlarge the most-probable keys for the next character. Really good for my fat fingers and thumbs.